# How to prove a certain app uses my library?

Tags: licensing, ios, mit-license

I am the author of an iOS framework and I know for sure that an app uses it, but the app's author is not attributing it.

How can I prove this in a way that also a judge would accept it?

Comment: Google for "reverse engineering ios app", will give you plenty of links.

Comment: You know, you could just ask the author.  And ask them for attribution if they do use your library.

Comment: @OskarSkog: if I would suspect someone else to violate my license terms, I would first gather as much evidence as possible before accusing or even asking him.

Answer (score 3):

*First*, the default MIT License (based on your tags) does not include an attribution clause ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)).  If you have that, then you've changed the base MIT license.  *Second*, the MIT license is a bit vague since it refers to a suite of compatible licenses.  *Third*, MIT license also suggests free use.  I'm not sure of the point of taking someone to court whom you won't be receiving money from.

The issue is that the burden of proof is on you.  Only you know the identifying markers of using your framework, or have the receipts of purchase.  If you suspect that someone is violating the terms of your license, and are prepared to go to court over the matter, then I recommend only one thing: **consult a lawyer**.  Only they can tell you the legal proof required in a court of law.

Comment: Sorry for my vague question. I want to know how I can technically prove that the current app version is using my library.

Comment: Not knowing anything about your framework, that would be difficult to suggest an answer.  Compound that with not knowing the specific legal proof needed, it's difficult to really answer your question.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: Hire a Digital Forensics Specialist, and a lawyer specialising in Software Copyright Infringement. The Forensics Specialist may be able to find clues in the app's code that your library was used. Then you sue the app's author, and using the clues the Forensics Specialist found, your lawyer convinces the judge to issue a warrant forcing the app's author to hand over the app's source code during discovery. Then, both parties unleash their Digital Forensics Specialists to prove or disprove the usage of your library, and the one with the more convincing arguments wins. The end.